# How to get attachments of multiple posts wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get attachments of multiple posts using wordpress function.

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
                     /*my question is how to pass multiple parents.*/
                     'post_parent' => 0,
                     'post_type'   => 'any', 
                     'posts_per_page' => -1,
                     'post_status' => 'any' );
               $children_array = get_children( $args, $output );
    ?>
```

Note*: I do not want to use loop for multiple posts.
               Because it increase the number of queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $args = array(
                 /*my question is how to pass multiple parents.*/
                 'post_parent' => array(0,1,etc),
                 'post_type'   => 'any', 
                 'posts_per_page' => -1,
                 'post_status' => 'any' );
           $children_array = get_children( $args, $output );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer David. But when I pass array to post_parent it consider it as null and return any child regardless of parent.